# How to load images and categorise with Unknown Prefix in filename?

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-gallery

This is the code which loads images with different Prefix and the prefix is printed under every image.

I need Prefix as a Title of every set of images as Category of Images

CODE :

```
 $images = glob($dirname . "*.jpg");
    foreach ($images as $image) {

        if (strpos($image, '#') !== false) {

        } else {
            ?>

    <li><?php $mn_img = str_replace("/thumbs", "", $image); ?>

        <div class="th [radius]">
            <a href="<?php echo $mn_img ?>"><img align="middle"
                src="<?php echo $image; ?>"> </a>
        </div>
        <p style="text-align: center">
            <?php
            $str = $mn_img;
            $s = end(explode("/", $str));

            $e = explode(".", $s);
            $n = explode('-', $e[0]);
            $nm = $n[0];
            if ($nm === 'non') {
                echo 'general';
            } else {
                $title = str_replace("_", " ", $nm);
                echo $title;
            }
            ?>
        </p>
    </li>

    <?php }
}
```

I expect the possibility :)

MY Prefix Format is

> Manager_fileoriginalname_random.jpg
>
> Manager_fileoriginalname_random.jpg
>
> Manager_fileoriginalname_random.jpg
>
> Manager_fileoriginalname_random.jpg
>
> Prefix is "**Manager**"
>
> Matketing_fileoriginalname_random.jpg
>
> Matketing_fileoriginalname_random.jpg
>
> Matketing_fileoriginalname_random.jpg
>
> Matketing_fileoriginalname_random.jpg
>
> Prefix is "**Marketing**"

Comment: if i got you well,then i have i suggestion for you.
use tag concept ,means save every image with at least one tag,
and then retrieve/list images under that specified tag.

Comment: Upload of images will not change now. I need solution for loading images according to its prefix

Answer (score 0):

is the `preg_match` function is what you want :

```
$returnValue = preg_match( '/(.*)_.*_.*$/', 'Manager_fileoriginalname_random.jpg', $matches );
```

in `$matches[1]` you have the prefix, you just need to remplace 'Manager_fileoriginalname_random.jpg' by your var `$mn_img`

If i can make and advise, can use `parse_url()` to extract url components : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.parse-url.php